# Remove parameter in abstract state angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

router, please refer below router config in app.js

```
$stateProvider
  .state('mySite', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'mySite.tpl.html',
    controller: 'mySiteController',
    controllerAs: 'mySiteApp'
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
  if ($location.url() === '' || $location.url() === '/'){
    $location.$$search = {};
    return '/home';
  }
  else {
    return '/404';
  }
```

In above web a user can come with a parameter in url, example lets say a user visits to site with **www.mysite.com?par=xxx** , then i handle the par within app.js. and i need to remove parameters before it route to child state. For example:
**www.mysite.com/home** instead of 
**www.mysite.com?par=xxx/home**
please note $location.$$search = {}; used above didn't worked as expected in this case. Please help me...

Comment: I think you should only use `.otherwise("/")` and have another state for `/` where it redirects. Or a `.otherwise("/404")` and state if you want to show an error page.

Comment: Also, as it is now, yours seems to be an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Please go through the link and see how to improve it. Also, see this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308444/ive-asked-an-xy-question-what-should-i-do-with-it

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but still not work for me, even didn't figure out the X yet. 
when i tried with the answer given above it redirects fine to correct page but didn't removes the parameter in URL instead it hides the path, ex: www.mysite.com?par=xxx/ instead of www.mysite.com/home

Comment: The X is similar to 'how redirecting works in angular', and Y is similar to 'I built this thing to redirect, but it doesn't work'. Instead of asking a question about what you've done, ask a question about what you want to do.

Comment: ok, simply, what i want is i have to remove URL parameters in abstract state  before redirecting to a child state. what is a best way to deal it? or i cant use abstract state here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, i found the solution and i'm not the first person stuck on this, the solution is enabling html5Mode...
[https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/372]